# Fill values into column of data frame based on two conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe where I would like to fill in values from column "reference column" into the column "trial_number" based on the following two conditions:

- condition 1: value column "start_time" >= value column "a" and
- condition 2: value column "end_time" <= value column "b"

The values should only be filled into column "trial_number" if both conditions are met at the same time.

One complication is that the columns "start_time" and "end_time" contain more values than columns "a", "b" and "reference_column". The idea is that each of the values in "reference_column" is filled in multiple rows of column "trial_number".

I as well have the columns "a", "b" and "reference_column" in a separate dataframe.

A simplified version of the dataframe looks like this:

```
 reference_column  a  b trial_number start_time end_time
1                 1 10 20           NA         12       18
2                 2 22 24           NA         22       23
3                 3 30 40           NA         23       24
4                 4 45 55           NA         31       32
5                NA NA NA           NA         35       36
6                NA NA NA           NA         36       37
7                NA NA NA           NA         37       39
8                NA NA NA           NA         46       51
9                NA NA NA           NA         47       53
10               NA NA NA           NA         50       54
```

In the end, the desired output (filled values in "trial_number" should look like this:

```
 reference_column  a  b trial_number start_time end_time
1                 1 10 20           01         12       18
2                 2 22 24           02         22       23
3                 3 30 40           02         23       24
4                 4 45 55           03         31       32
5                NA NA NA           03         35       36
6                NA NA NA           03         36       37
7                NA NA NA           03         37       39
8                NA NA NA           04         46       51
9                NA NA NA           04         47       53
10               NA NA NA           04         50       54
```

Since I am quite new to R, I would be very happy about any recommendations. I already tried to use a for loop in combination with an if-statement, but wasn't successful because of the unbalanced number of data entries and various conditions. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Hi sa-al, welcome to SO! Some thoughts. *I as well have the columns "a", "b" and "reference_column" in a separate dataframe.* Taking this info into consideration would change any helping approach significantly. Either include the other data frames or maybe generate a small [minimal but still complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/9462095). Any help you receive based on the current data will either be incomplete or unintentionally misleading.

Comment: Hi Andre, Thanks a lot for your answer! What I wanted to express with this is that I have the exact same columns with same values stored in a separate dataframe. They contain the same information as the columns in the dataframe I have included here as a very simplified example. Just thought the separate dataframe might help if the problem cannot be solved with all information in one dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this approach would be helpful?

Dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(referenceColumn = seq(from =1, to = 10, by =1), 
                 a = c(10, 22, 30, 45, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                 b = c(20, 24, 40, 55, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
                 trialNumber = rep(NA, 10), 
                 startTime = c(12, 22, 23, 31, 35, 36, 37, 46, 47, 50), 
                 endTime = c(18, 23, 24, 32, 36, 37, 39, 51, 53, 54))
```

Separate your reference table and dataset

```
dimDf <- df %>% 
  select(referenceColumn:b) 
              

factDf <- df %>% 
  select(trialNumber:endTime)
```

Use your reference table in a case_when()

```
dfNew <- factDf %>% 
  mutate(trialNumber = case_when(
    startTime >= dimDf$a[1] & endTime <= dimDf$b[1] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[1], 
    startTime >= dimDf$a[2] & endTime <= dimDf$b[2] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[2], 
    startTime >= dimDf$a[3] & endTime <= dimDf$b[3] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[3], 
    startTime >= dimDf$a[4] & endTime <= dimDf$b[4] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[4],
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ))
```

[image: example]

or keep all columns

```
dfNew <- df %>% 
  mutate(trialNumber = case_when(
    startTime >= dimDf$a[1] & endTime <= dimDf$b[1] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[1], 
    startTime >= dimDf$a[2] & endTime <= dimDf$b[2] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[2], 
    startTime >= dimDf$a[3] & endTime <= dimDf$b[3] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[3], 
    startTime >= dimDf$a[4] & endTime <= dimDf$b[4] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[4],
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  ))
```

[image: example 2]

Comment: Okay, I see the logic now.  Really is two separate tables, and that was confusing.  This is the right approach.

Comment: Hi Susan, Thanks a lot for the suggested approach. My original reference dataframe has 324 rows, is there any way to perform this "startTime >= dimDf$a[1] & endTime <= dimDf$b[1] ~ dimDf$referenceColumn[1]" in an automated way for all 324 rows? And I tried your code and unfortunately received the following error:

Comment: Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `trial_number = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:
! `..2 (right)` must be a vector, not `NULL`.
Backtrace:
 1. fix_updated_n %>% ...
 9. dplyr::case_when(...)

Comment: Do you have an idea why this error is occurring?

Comment: Hi! I do not have a variable named trial_number (snake case with underscore) in my example. Mine is named trialNumber (camelCase). Looks like just a little naming diff.

Comment: I'd imagine there is a way to scale up to 300+ rows in your reference table with a function, but that is beyond my skills. Perhaps when you update your variable names and get my example to work you could repost another inquiry about scaling up using my example?

Comment: Hi Susan, I could now fix the error, was simply a spelling mistake :) Only the scaling up still does not work / gives me a hard time. But might be a good idea to post another question with you example about that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is going to be incomplete because I don't fully understand what you are doing with this statement:

> *One complication is that the columns "start_time" and "end_time" contain more values than columns "a", "b" and "reference_column". The idea is that each of the values in "reference_column" is filled in multiple rows of column "trial_number".*

But I think I have some directional help:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~reference_column,  ~a,  ~b, ~trial_number, ~start_time, ~end_time,
               1, 10, 20,           NA,         12,       18,
               2, 22, 24,           NA,         22,       23,
               3, 30, 40,           NA,         23,       24,
               4, 45, 55,           NA,         31,       32,
              NA, NA, NA,           NA,         35,       36,
              NA, NA, NA,           NA,         36,       37,
              NA, NA, NA,           NA,         37,       39,
              NA, NA, NA,           NA,         46,       51,
              NA, NA, NA,           NA,         47,       53,
              NA, NA, NA,           NA,         50,       54)


df %>% 
  mutate(trial_number = if_else(start_time >= a & end_time <= b, 
                                reference_column,
                                trial_number))

# A tibble: 10 × 6
   reference_column     a     b trial_number start_time end_time
              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1                1    10    20            1         12       18
 2                2    22    24            2         22       23
 3                3    30    40           NA         23       24
 4                4    45    55           NA         31       32
 5               NA    NA    NA           NA         35       36
 6               NA    NA    NA           NA         36       37
 7               NA    NA    NA           NA         37       39
 8               NA    NA    NA           NA         46       51
 9               NA    NA    NA           NA         47       53
10               NA    NA    NA           NA         50       54
```

In your example output, you find some way to put values for "trial_number" even where `df$a` and `df$b` are `== NA`.  Please either explain the additional logic in your question, or hopefully this is enough to give you some ideas how to proceed.

Comment: Hi wackojacko1997, Thanks a lot for your answer and suggested approach. I tried it on my data and it unfortunately doesn't produce the intended result since the column "trial_number" is still empty after running the code. It does not lead to any errors though.

Comment: To explain what I meant about the unbalanced number of values: I thought this could be an issue that the values to be filled into "trial_number" are not always the same index of the dataframe than the values to be filled in from column "reference_column". Same with the columns / values to be compared in "a", "b", "start_time", and "end_time".

Comment: To give an example: row 7 from "trial_number" needs to be filled with the value from row 3 from "reference_column" (=3) since "start_time" in row 7 >= "a" in row 3 and "end_time" in row 7 is <= "b" in row 3. Hope this makes sense and sorry for the complicated explanations. Could as well be that this is not an issue - as already mentioned, I am still in the progress of learning!

Comment: @sa-al, I still don't follow the logic you're applying. Why are you comparing row 3 with row 7?  Are these related as `row_number() %% 4` ?  Why don't you compare row 3 with row 5, for example?  Potentially if this is a modulo relationship, you could create `new_column = row_number() %% 4`, then `group_by(new_column)` and use `fill()` to carry forward values from row 3 to row 7... I'm just not sure what the logic really is that you're using, but you could look at those to see if it helps you.